Why was my answer the the question about restricting leaving Israel deleted?
I answered this question with a direct link to the Israeli law provision on the topic. Seems factual and well-sourced to me. Why was it deleted? I didn't even see any usual antisemitic comments addressed to me.

The answer was first posted when the question still read like this. The answer wasn't an answer to the question. It was merely pointing out a misconception in the question. So I converted it to a comment.
Then the question was edited so the comment no longer applied, so the comment wasn't on-topic anymore either. So I deleted the comment.
However, now reading the deleted answer again in the context of the current version of the question, it actually is now on-topic. I just undeleted it. But I removed the quote from the previous version of the question that is no longer in the current version.

Thanks, I guess I missed some action overnight.
